# How to refer to HEAD on a different branch?

Tags: git

I am using Git Bash under Windows and am thus unable to select the commit hashes with the mouse.

I now want to cherry-pick individual recent commits from a feature branch into master. I am looking for syntax in the order of `git cherry-pick HEAD~5@coolbranch`. Does something similar exist?

Comment: Note that `HEAD` is completely independent of any branch. It often refers to a branch, but `HEAD` is "what I currently have checked out in my working copy" - it may be a symbolic reference to a branch, meaning "I have the tip of that branch checked out", or it may be a hash, meaning "I have this specific commit checked out". There is no `HEAD` on any branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git cherry-pick coolbranch~5`. This should work since `HEAD` is synonymous to "your current revision".  So if you are on `master` under the commit `abc12345`, then `HEAD = master = abc12345`.

Note, I didn't test this -- but I did try `git diff --shortstat feature/branch~5` and it worked as expected.

Comment: This should work. It's possible to `git show` a commit from another branch like this so cherry picking should work as well

Comment: Thanks, Sam. As so often happens, no I see how silly my question was. Heck, I used `git show coolbranch~2` just before getting stuck with the above question. I guess programmer productivity is like mana points - you exhaust them and need to recharge with beer and sleep.